# Check whether "always ask me to download" is checked in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In the chrome extnesions download API you can call the following:

```
    chrome.downloads.download({
        url: URL,
        filename: filePathAndName,
        saveAs:false
    }
```

As you can see this has an option to disable the "save as" feature and force the save at the desired location.

This option is overpowered by the chrome user setting "always ask me where to download."

Is there any way to programatically determine whether this setting is checked or not?  My user's experience will be different than expected if they she is greeted with a "save as" window and therefore I would like to be able to offer instruction in that event.

Comment: My usual answer: there's no API to read it. But I want to have fun: 1) write an external nativeMessaging app that reads the user profile and chrome policy settings, 2) create a window with `url: 'chrome://settings/search#save'` and use chrome.desktopCapture API to screenshot it, then analyze the pixels to read the checkbox state which obviously is language-dependent but you can find the [label translations](https://cs.chromium.org/search/?q=7754704193130578113) in chromium source code.

Comment: See man.  This is the sort of crazy answer I look for.  Greatly appreciated.  Definitely not going to do it but greatly appreciate the thought!

Comment: You will need to add a warning for all users to disable that option. Open bug, https://crbug.com/417112